# how to change Woocommerce shopping cart icon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

How can I change the Woocommerce shopping cart icon? I am using theme OceanWp

Any help is much appreciated!

## EDIT

The theme that I used, added the ability to change it in the customizer

Answer (score 1):

You can change the icon from wordpress theme customizer. Make use of [this](https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/190-remove-or-edit-the-woocommerce-menu-icon)

- Go the theme submenu and click on Customize
- Go to woocommerce
- You can see the options there.

Comment: am i missing something?
because i dont have the option for that

Comment: I cannot say anything without seeing the back end. I have checked the documentation and founded the link (used in above answer)

Comment: i gave my site address above, is it helping?

Comment: I think admin side is required.

Comment: cant you see it in the 'inspect'?
but i found out how to do it, thank you

Comment: @amir If you have found the answer, please post it as answer for this question. Some one will find it helpful

Comment: I cant see that option either can you please share how did you do it?  @melvin

Comment: @KaranSethi I don't remember where the icon was, may be it's available in premium version

Comment: @melvin no problem I figured it out and added it as an answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

Adding this in additional css worked for me,
Get your favorite icon code from here - https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet
and paste it as shown below...

```
.site-header-cart .cart-contents::after {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    content: "\f217"; /*paste it here*/
    height: 1em;
    float: right;
    line-height: 1.618; 

    }
```